# Can I go back to an older version of Java?

Tags: windows-7, java

My dlink ip cameras have stopped showing live video since a java update, can I go back to an older version of java ? if so how?

Comment: Uninstall the version you have then install an older version? This will of course be less secure ...

Answer (score 1):

There is a guide on [java.com](https://java.com/en/download/faq/other_jreversions.xml) on how to  get older versions of Java. Do read the note on security risks.

Comment: Pretty much - you generally can 'just' uninstall java and reinstall the last known good version

Answer (score 1):

You can run multiple version of the JRE on one machine; this has been discussed at StackExchange at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271609/multiple-java-versions-running-concurrently-under-windows. See also https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/managing_multiple_java_versions.

As mentioned, Java is continually patched for security, among other issues, so you want the default JRE to be the *most recen*t, and have the older run only with your D-Link software.